# How to retrieve key-value pair from hash value of the URL

Tags: javascript

I am learning the OAuth2 flow with Google (https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/javascript-implicit-flow#oauth-2.0-endpoints), I am NOT using Google's JS Client library. At the step where Google returns a hash value to my redirect URL, which looks something like this:

```
http://localhost:3000/profile#access_token=ya29.A0AfH6SMCKcSSl4-KfeV7oioFYN_LHpJ9Z_cnpY5yHCK4d8U1TdaZ-TXU05XfzNZsmfNA1Csla-f8U3k4Jp9uYzCzmkIJf1qs5k_hle5ArwBm462_TPfuTtn5bbnN-hD5Bn7m9TEpxF3vmez81IU-AgNHhMwgr&token_type=Bearer&expires_in=3599&scope=profile%20https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile
```

How can I retrieve the values from the hash value like access_token? What I have so far is this which retrieves the hash value without the #:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';

const Profile = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    if (window.location.hash) {
      console.log(window.location.hash.substr(1));
    } else {
      console.log('no hash');
    }
  });
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Profile page</h1>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Profile;
```

PS: I am using NextJS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`URLSearchParams`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) to make this easier for you.

```js
const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.hash.substr(1))
```

You can access values like `access_token` like so:

```js
urlParams.get('access_token')
```